# Laravel how do I use forelse() on table?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using a forelse statement on a table as:

```
@forelse($message->content->suggestions as $suggestion)
                <td>
                    @foreach ($message->content->suggestions as $suggestion)
                    <span class='badge badge-info'>{{($suggestion->reply->text)}}</span>
                    @endforeach
                </td>
                @empty
                    <em> - </em>
                @endforelse
```

My goal is to check if the table has data called suggestions then run the foreach() however if it's empty just show "-" this is my first time using forelse and wanted to learn it :) If I can't do it this way can someone share how to do it with IF statement instead?

Can you see what I am doing wrong, if I open a table without suggestions I just get a error instead of "-"

Table giving error looks like:

```
"id" => "3d0ef00c-0edd-4d8b-ad1c-27e92e29c469"
"method" => "rcs"
"msisdn" => 64224603
"direction" => "mt"
"type" => "text"
"status" => "delivered"
"content" => "{"text":"Dial a number"}"
"suggestion_id" => null
"created_at" => 1591669329
"updated_at" => 1591669333
"deleted_at" => null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this...

```
@if(!empty($message->content->suggestions))
    // There is are suggestions
    @foreach($message->content->suggestions as $suggestion)
        <span class='badge badge-info'>{{ $suggestion->reply->text }}</span>
    @endforeach
@else
    // No Suggestions
    <span class='badge badge-info'>-</span>
@endif
```

This checks if suggestions are available and if so loops through them, if not, displays a -. Also assuming your relationships are setup correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Thry this. I have used this way in one of my project.

```
@forelse($message->content->suggestions as $suggestion)
<td>

<span class='badge badge-info'>{{($suggestion->reply->text)}}</span>

</td>
@empty
 <span> - </span>
@endforelse
```

Try this

Comment: It didn't work but I needed the foreach loop to stay, I just did it with @ahackney answer using an IF statement. Thanks for trying to help though :)